# Why does this <li> get added multiple times?

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/ay9d8cuq/3/

To recreate, try adding a location/service filter more than once.  Notice how it adds empty items to the list.

Why does this code add the filter more than once to the DOM?

```
$('#addFilter').click(function(){
    var filter = $('#FilterTypes').val();

    switch (filter)
    {
        case "Location":
                $('#LocationFilter').show()
                .find('.addFilter').click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                    AddLocationFilter();
                });
                break;
            case "Service":
                $('#ServiceFilter').show()
                .find('.addFilter').click(function() {
                    $(this).parent().hide();
                    AddServiceFilter();
                });
                break;
    }
});

var AddLocationFilter = function() {
    $('#Filters').append('<li>' + $('#City').val() + ', ' + $('#State').val() + '</li>');
    $('#City').val('');
    $('#State').val('');
};

var AddServiceFilter = function() {
    $('#Filters').append('<li>' + $('#Name').val() + '</li>');
    $('#Name').val('');
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because you're re-attaching the `click` handler every time the `AddFilter` button is clicked, so for the second time it will run twice.

Try this instead:

```
.find('.addFilter').one('click', function() {
```

And

```
.find('.addFilter').one('click', function() {
```

See [one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) and [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ay9d8cuq/9/)

Comment: Awesome, never knew about that method.

Comment: Well, for the sake of completeness, you didn't really have to attach the events upon `addFilter` click, it's only the `show()` you're interested in upon clicking. You could have taken the event binding outside the `#addFilter.click()` handler and that would have probably solved everything.

Answer (score 4):

Each time you click the `Add Filter` button, you add a listener to the `Add` button, which mean that if you click 3 times on `Add Filter` with `Location` selected, the listener is called 3 times and you get 3 entries in your list.

This code:

```
$('#LocationFilter').find('.addFilter').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().hide();
    AddLocationFilter();
});
```

Should be outside your click callback (same for ServiceFilter).

Answer (score 2):

You're adding a new `click()` handler to one of the `.addFilter` buttons every time `#addFilter` is clicked. They all call the same function, which adds an entry then clears the field values. The next "copy" of the handler then runs, adding those empty values.

Set the handlers once:

```js
$('#addFilter').click(function() {
  var filter = $('#FilterTypes').val();

  switch (filter) {
    case "Location":
      $('#LocationFilter').show();
      break;
    case "Service":
      $('#ServiceFilter').show();
      break;
  }
});


$('#LocationFilter .addFilter').
click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
  AddLocationFilter();
});

$('#ServiceFilter .addFilter').
click(function() {
  $(this).parent().hide();
  AddServiceFilter();
});

var AddLocationFilter = function() {
  $('#Filters').append('<li>' + $('#City').val() + ', ' + $('#State').val() + '</li>');
  $('#City').val('');
  $('#State').val('');
};

var AddServiceFilter = function() {
  $('#Filters').append('<li>' + $('#Name').val() + '</li>');
  $('#Name').val('');
};
```

```css
#LocationFilter,
#ServiceFilter {
  display: none;
}
div,
ul,
select {
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="FilterTypes">
  <option value="Location">Location</option>
  <option value="Service">Service</option>
</select>
<a href="#" id="addFilter">Add filter</a>
<div id="LocationFilter">
  <h4>Add Location Filter</h4>
  <input id="City" placeholder="City" />
  <input id="State" placeholder="State" />
  <input type="button" class="addFilter" value="Add">
</div>
<div id="ServiceFilter">
  <h4>Add Service Filter</h4>
  <input id="Name" placeholder="Service name" />
  <input type="button" class="addFilter" value="Add">
</div>
<ul id="Filters"></ul>
```